# Capture a event when all the threads are executed in Executor framework

Tags: java, listener, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Im using Java Executor framework to execute multiple threads at a same time. I would like to do some operations after all the threads are executed. Do we have any listeners or event capture mechanism in executor framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider moving from a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). The difference is, that for all the tasks you enqueue, you'll get a [`Future<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

This allows you to check for `.isDone()` of tasks you submitted and act accordingly. Especially interesting if you need to use results of what you submitted, because you can cleanly perform a `.get()` then, without blocking the calling thread until the execution is finished.

Another alternative might be to implement a `ThreadFactory`, which spawns an additional listener thread to `join()` the main thread and notify you upon completion.

Comment: Yeah, using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is probably the best/cleanest approach

Answer (score 4):

The API docks for ThreadPoolExecutor describe some hooks that might be useful for this:

> Hook methods
>
> This class provides protected overridable beforeExecute(java.lang.Thread, java.lang.Runnable) and
>   afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable, java.lang.Throwable) methods that are
>   called before and after execution of each task. These can be used to
>   manipulate the execution environment; for example, reinitializing
>   ThreadLocals, gathering statistics, or adding log entries.
>   Additionally, method terminated() can be overridden to perform any
>   special processing that needs to be done once the Executor has fully
>   terminated.
>
> If hook or callback methods throw exceptions, internal worker threads may in turn fail and abruptly terminate.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 1):

```
        A a = new A();
        B b= new B();
        FutureTask fa = new FutureTask (a);
        FutureTask fb = new FutureTask (b);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); 
        es.submit (fa);
        es.submit(fb);



        String getName = (String)a.get();
        String getSurName = (String)b.get();

        es.shutdown ();

        ***//Here all threads are executed and 
        //you can write any code which you want to execute after 
         //finishing all the threads.***
```

Or the other work around .
....
you can write daemon class by using `LocalThrad` class and spawn the thread and it will act as listener for you.

Whatever you want to achieve in this case you can achieve by using above daemon class.

Comment: shutdown() doesnt block. This is not secure, the tasks may still be running after shutdown(). So that is not true what you said. Is there no mechanism like shutdown) which blocks until all tasks are finished?